# Jquery/Ajax, MySQL, 20 textfields, auto update

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I've been looking through multiple sites to find an answer, but since I'm a total noob on jQuery, please bear with me.

I have a page that someone has requested auto populate field names based on the first text field.

```
<input type="text" size=4 name="team_ID:3" class="teamNumberCls">
<input type="text" name="teamname:3" id="teamname:3"></td>
<input type="text" size=2 name="score:3">

<input type="text" size=4 name="team_ID:4" class="teamNumberCls">
<input type="text" name="teamname:4" id="teamname:4">
<input type="text" size=2 name="score:4">

<input type="text" size=4 name="team_ID:5" class="teamNumberCls">
<input type="text" name="teamname:5" value="" id="teamname:5">
<input type="text" size=2 name="score:5">
```

Input would be done on the `team_ID:` field and then we'd do some kind of ajax call.  I probably can figure out the ajax call, but I'm not totally sure how to get the value from each of the cells since there are going to be 20 different ones on a page.  Once I get the team ID, I can do a query and find out the team name from the ajax call.

Comment: I would assume you can just use `$('form').serialize()`? I think that is what you are trying to do?

Comment: You should use names of the form `team_ID[]`, `teamname[]`, etc. Server libraries that process parameters will normally put these values into an array.